# FFMPEG cut out specific section of audio/video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to cut out specific parts from audio/video files. Attempting something like

`ffmpeg -ss 132 -i input.mp3 output.mp3`

seems to do the exact opposite of what I want and only give me the section i want to cut out.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/681885/how-can-i-remove-multiple-segments-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg